# Compliant mechanism that can resist shear force

Tags: mechanisms, shear, hinge

Looking for a compliant mechanism that can witsdent sheat force but still move in another axis

Is there such compliant mechanism that can resist shear force but still bend like a hinge?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a device is called a compliant hinge or a flexure hinge. Here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WceyxTb_xVc